# Cannot load iFrame source code which relies on logging in through 3rd party

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe, webdriver

I'm a beginner trying to write a program that automatically downloads lectures from my university website. I'm currently trying to use Selenium Webdriver to do this, and i've managed to succeed up to the point where I actually choose lectures which are located in an iFrame, like so

[image]

The trouble is, when I switch to the relevant iFrame, it doesn't actually load any of the elements I need to navigate find all the links to download my lectures, it only gives me this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body><iframe 
frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" src="https://content.lecture.unimelb.edu.au/ess/portal/section/MAST10005_2017_SM1
"></iframe></body></html>
```

When I follow the link, it redirects me to a login page for the 3rd party company who do the lectures, which I don't actually have a login for.

[image]

Here's the code i'm using to try access the iFrame:

```
browser.get(recording_link)
time.sleep(3)
browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_id("contentFrame"))

for date in browser.find_element_by_class_name("echo-title"):
    print date.get_attribute("text")
```

and here's the iFrame i'm trying to access:

```
<iframe id="contentFrame" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 687px;" 
frameborder="0" name="content" title="&nbsp;" src="/webapps/osc-BasicLTI-
bb_bb60/frame.jsp?
course_id=_327002_1&amp;id=lectur&amp;&amp;globalNavigation=false" 
cd_frame_id_="d8705f0d279e5852eaa333951cffc5bf"></iframe>
```

Everything I need to access is beneath a #document tag, which i'm not getting.

I'm assuming I can't access any of the elements I need due to the need to login through the 3rd party. I've tried to "wait" for the source code to load, but it doesn't work. Is there any way to navigate around this?

Comment: The way I see it it is an added layer of security, If this is the case then why are you navigating to the `<iframe>` link just switch to `<iframe>` using `driver.switchTo().frame();` and then download all the lectures from there without navigating away from the original page.

Comment: The reason i'm navigating to it is so I can see what the source code looks like when I access the frame. So far, after trying to look through all of the possible iFrames, none of them actually have the content I want.